# Flutter using FirebaseAuth, I had a problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Flutter using FirebaseAuth, I had a problem.

I try to using code when user is register.

```
// get user details
Future<model.User> getUserDetails() async {
  User currentUser = _auth.currentUser!;
  //print(currentUser.uid);

  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
      await _firestore.collection('Users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();

  return model.User.fromSnap(documentSnapshot);
}
```

It's can write in Authentication, but can't write in Cloud Firestore.

It feels that because Cloud Firestore has not written it, it grabs the data, so there is an error.

the error line is `DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await _firestore.collection('Users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();`

The error:

> Exception caught by widgets library
>
> The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building MobileScreenLayout(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<UserProvider?>], state: _MobileScreenLayoutState#2677b):
> Unexpected null value.

how do I solve it?

auth code

```
if (email.isNotEmpty ||
          password.isNotEmpty ||
          username.isNotEmpty ||
          bio.isNotEmpty) {
        //register user
        UserCredential cred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        print(cred.user!.uid);

        String photoUrl =
            await StorageMethods().uploadImageToStorage('uploads', file, false);

        //add user to our databse
        model.User user = model.User(
          username: username,
          password: password,
          id: cred.user!.uid,
          email: email,
          bio: bio,
          blue_check: '0',
          country: 'Australia',
          userimage: photoUrl,
          followers: [],
          following: [],
        );

        await _firestore.collection('Users').doc(cred.user!.uid).set(
              user.toJson(),
            );
```

user.dart

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "bio": bio,
        "blue_check": '0',
        "country": 'Australia',
        "email": email,
        "followers": followers,
        "following": following,
        "id": id,
        "password": password,
        "userimage": userimage,
        "username": username,
      };
```

Comment: the question is not clear, is your user authenticated when you use the code above or not ?

Comment: @tareqalbeesh user will use email to register

Comment: "can't write in Cloud Firestore." Why not? What is keeping it from doing that? Is there an error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen should be is ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building MobileScreenLayout(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<UserProvider?>], state: _MobileScreenLayoutState#2677b):
Unexpected null value.

Comment: How do you know that the line you mentioned throws that error? Could you paste further messages connected with this error?